# Reducing duplicate code between emscripten-compiled JS files

Tags: javascript, emscripten

Let's say I compile two C libraries to JavaScript using emscripten, e.g. `sdl.js` and `openal.js`. I output them as separate files because I don't necessarily want to use both of them all the time. Is it possible to tell emcc to put all the libc code in a third shared file so that the two libraries aren't much larger than they need to be?